# git flow (avh edition) hooks are not executed

Tags: git, githooks, git-flow

I had the problem, that hooks that reside in my global hook directory `~/git-hooks` are not executed.

Namely the git-flow dependent hook `post-flow-release-start` just wasn't called, while the hook `pre-commit` was called without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git-flow-avh is unable to deal with the `~` character in the path to the hooks. Changing  it to an absolute path `/Users/atripes/git-hooks` worked.